# How to delete a child record when there ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans-7, many-to-one, cascading-deletes

Table grpUsuario

```
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "grupo")
        private Integer grupo;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
        @Column(name = "descripcion")
        private String descripcion;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "secLevel")
        private Collection<Menu> menuCollection;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "grupo", orphanRemoval = true)
        private Collection<Usuario> usuarioCollection;ç
```

Table Usuario

```
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "IdUsuario")
    private String idUsuario;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 16)
    @Column(name = "nombres")
    private String nombres;

    @Size(max = 24)
    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    private String apellidos;

    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Correo electrónico no válido")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 64)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idUsuario")
    private Collection<Encuesta> encuestaCollection;

    @JoinColumn(name = "grupo", referencedColumnName = "grupo" )
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Grpusuario grupo;
```

Controller

```
String cod = request.getParameter("cod");
Usuario usuario= new Usuario(cod);
boolean resultado = usuario_servicio.delete(usuario);
```

Function to delete

```
 public boolean delete(Usuario usuario){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();  
        Transaction tx = null;        
        try {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            session.delete(usuario);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }        
        return true;
    }
```

This is the code that I have but I did not delete the record. This same code I've tried to tables that have relationships and if it works that more should I do to work me to delete child records?

Comment: Do you get a warning or exception when trying to delete this instance?  I haven't tried, but usually the entity needs to be loaded before deleting it.

Comment: Shows no exepcion , the opposite resultado is true and shows the message Record Deleted succesfull. But record exist.

Comment: What happens when you replace that delete by a `session.delete(session.get(Usuario.class, usuario.getIdUsuario()))`, assuming that `cod` is your PK?

Comment: Thanks, yes the PK is `cod` and replace `Session.delete(usuario)` by `session.delete (session.get (Usuario.class, usuario.getIdUsuario ()))` and it run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: the entity needs to be in the persistence context for Hibernate to properly delete it. So the solution is to fetch it using Hibernate first.

Replace

```
session.delete(usuario);
```

with

```
session.delete(session.get(Usuario.class, usuario.getIdUsuario()));
```

Be careful: `get()` can return `null` values if the entity is no longer in the database, so you better check for that before passing the object to `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the registres and later deletes with SQL.